# Como permitir asignar una fecha nula?

Tags: c#

Como puedo asignar una fecha nula a una variable del tipo DateTime?

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
DateTime? FechaNula = new DateTime?();
deudaDto.FechaIngreso = deuda.FechaIngreso.HasValue ? deuda.FechaIngreso : FechaNula;
```

pero me marca error, dice que no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo System.DateTime? en System.DateTime....

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Claramente, `FechaIngreso` no es nullable. Asi que todo depende de lo que consideres como `null` en un tipo de datos que no acepta null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código debe funcionar

```
DateTime FechaNula = new DateTime();
deudaDto.FechaIngreso = deuda.FechaIngreso.HasValue ? deuda.FechaIngreso.Value : FechaNula;
```

Al parecer `deudaDto.FechaIngreso` es de tipo `DateTime` por lo que requiere que la expresión de la derecha no sea nula

Una forma más corta de lograr lo mismo sería

```
deudaDto.FechaIngreso = deuda.FechaIngreso ?? new DateTime();
```

Que significa que si `FechaIngreso` no es nula que se asigne su valor, de lo contrario se asigne un `new DateTime()` (la fecha "nula")

Comment: error mio, me confundi entre la declaracion del DTO, y la de la clase que define en la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Por que si le vas a asignar una fecha nula a deudaDto.FechaIngreso, ésta debe ser también nullable, tu declaración de la propiedad debe verse asi :

```
public DateTime? FechaIngreso {get; set;}
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion, ya lo solucione. saludos